# Running a JAVA Program with a Button (GUI)

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jsoup, jxl

I've been stumped on this all day, despite hours of research. Below is a basic idea of my program. It extracts data from links and puts it into a spreadsheet, and it can run for hours at a time. My intent is to connect this to a GUI with a progress bar. I'm trying to have an "upload" button, then a "Run" button.

For the "Run" button, I cannot figure out how to connect the button to running an instance of the below program.

I have attempted putting

```
App obj= new App();
obj.main(null);
```

under actionPerformed with no luck. I receive the following error:

```
Error:(31, 25) java: unreported exception java.lang.Exception; 
    must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

I understand now that we can't exactly call main functions. But in that case, how can I make my program work with a GUI? The main reason behind this is to be able to create a webapp for it in the future so that I can access it anywhere.

```
public class App {

private static final int[] URL_COLUMNS = { 0, 4, 9 }; // Columns A, E, J
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

    Workbook originalWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/original.xls"));
    WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/Shadow/Desktop/updated.xls"), originalWorkbook);
    originalWorkbook.close();
    WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
    Cell cell;

    for (int i = 0; i < URL_COLUMNS.length; i++) {
        int currentRow = 1;
        while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMNS[i], currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {

            String url = cell.getContents();
            System.out.println("Checking URL: " + url);
            if (url.contains("scrapingsite1.com")) {
                String Price = ScrapingSite1(url);
                System.out.println("Scraping Site1's Price: " + Price);
                // save price into the next column
                Label cellWithPrice = new Label(URL_COLUMNS[i] + 1, currentRow, Price);
                sheet.addCell(cellWithPrice);
            }
            currentRow++;
        }
    }

    workbook.write();
    workbook.close();
}

private static String ScrapingSite1 (String url) throws IOException {
    Document doc = null;
    for (int i=1; i <= 6; i++) {
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(6000).validateTLSCertificates(false).get();
            break;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Jsoup issue occurred " + i + " time(s).");
        }
    }
    if (doc == null){
        return null;
    }
    else{
        return doc.select("p.price").text();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Which is line 31 ? Why do you `break` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a crude guess I would say that the compiler is prompting you to change:

```
App obj= new App();
obj.main(null);
```

To one of several possibilities, this one based on 'must be caught' (`try` / `catch`):

```
try {
    App obj= new App();
    obj.main(null);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // good fall back if logging not implemented
}
```

**Edit:** For more information, see the [Exceptions lesson](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html) of the Java Tutorial.

Comment: Amazing, this worked. Do you happen to know why? Java has been fairly difficult for me to catch on to and these sorts of things certainly don't help to run into!

Comment: See the edit to answer, with link to relevant section of the Java Tutorial.